# Restore [non-boot drive] root directory from kernel image

Tags: linux, partitioning, kernel

Accidentally overwrote the root directory on a 2nd drive, .. but the subdirectories are still there [i.e. cd to a subdirectory drive is successful].

Problem is, the *root* directory in the partition is blank, and testdisk says the file system is damaged.

The kernel image must be intact, else the subdirectories would not be accessible - so how would write the *kernel* copy of the partition table and root directory to write back to the disk?

Cannot unmount the drive or reboot else the kernel copy would be lost.

Comment: Unfortunately the question you have asked is non-sensical (ie you have asked questions which don't make sense to someone with the knowledge to answer).  It might be an idea to rewrite the question explaining symptoms.   A couple of problems - by Kernel do you mean "in-memory" version of the filesystem (its doubtful a kernel image is relevant and means something different to what you may think) ?  Also, is this a problem with the filesystem ?  If so, why do you talk about the partition table being at fault ?

Comment: Would the correct answer not be to scp the files to another system and rebuild your problem system ?   Also, what command did you issue to cause the problem  - that will provide insite into what has happened and may help with recovery suggestions.

Comment: "It might be an idea to rewrite the question explaining symptoms. A couple of problems - by Kernel do you mean "in-memory" version of the filesystem" - Of course, .. I cannot envision any other possible interpretation on a running system.   "Also, is this a problem with the filesystem?" Sorry, I thought it was fairly descriptive - i.e. the root directory is blank, yet I can access subdirectories directly. "Would the correct answer not be to scp the files to another system and rebuild your problem system?" Only if I had a record of subdirectories, ..

Appreciate any suggestions, ..

Comment: Do you know the filesystem you are using (Is ext4 a reasonable guess?)   If so, how about using ssh and dd to make a bit copy of the drive then attempting recovery using extundelete on the copy of the block device ?   Can you ssh in or out of the machine ?

Comment: I hesitate to use extundelete as it will require unmounting the file system. Would anyone have a suggestion on pulling the kernel copy from memory?

Comment: I was proposing to do an extundelete on the copy you made by dragging the system through the network (ie over ssh).  Yes, the backup will be unclean, but with minimal disk writes it should be OK.

Comment: Don't know of any way to do a block copy via ssh, .. copying the active filesystem on the drive would just propagate the errors. Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: if you can ssh into the failing system -  ssh "dd if=/dev/sdX" > file.name   otherwise if you can push out the block device using a command like "dd if=/dev/sdX | ssh user@exthost.name "dd > block.dev" - SSH is designed to work with pipes.  Yes, the fact the drive is active will mean errors propogate, but so what - you will still get virtually all the data in a copied device you can safely manipulate without risk to your main system.